# how python manage object delete or destruction

Tags: python, oop, object, destruction

guys, I am rather new to python and learning it to build a gui application (with wypython). I have a question related with object destruction in python. 
e.g. in myFrame I have onNew (create a new document) and onOpen (open a file) method.

briefly, it looks like this.

```
def onNew
    self.data=DataModel()
    self.viewwindow=ViewWindow(self.data)


def onOpen
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Open file", os.getcwd(), "", "*.*", wx.OPEN)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.data=DataModel.from_file(...)
            self.view=View(self.data)
```

now, I want to consider "if the user click open or new again, after he click either before."

so for the window classes, I could call the `self.viewwindow.Destroy()` to destry the windows. what about the data model object? If I first call new: `self.data=DataModel()`, then call open and re-assign `self.data=DataModel.from_file(...)`, what about the old instance? Do I need destruct it myself or python will manage this destruction?

Comment: *shudder* wxPython likes to do its own things with the lifetimes of the underlying C++ objects, so don't trust Python to be able to do the right thing.

Comment: HI, AaronMcSmooth, you mean wxpython has the GC and trustable, while python is not trustable?

Comment: I don't recommend learning Python by using it with a GUI toolkit; start with console tools to learn the language so you don't pick up bad habits and misunderstandings due to the API quirks of a particular GUI.  Most GUI toolkits are bindings to a lower-level API which isn't designed with Python in mind, so they don't tend to behave as nicely as modules designed for Python from the start.

Comment: I mean that just because wxWidgets has assigned the underlying C++ object to a C++ field doesn't mean that wxPython has assigned the Python object to a Python attribute, which means that your C++ object that is in use will be deallocated when the Python object goes out of scope, causing your program to blow up. Like when using a `wxImageList` with a `wxList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has garbage collection. As long as you don't have any references to the old object hanging around it will be collected.

As soon as you say `self.data = somethingElse` then the old `self.data` won't have any references to it (unless another object had a reference to your object's `self.data`).

Comment: It might be collected.  It might not.  You should never assume that you know anything about how the GC works - if you're not running out of memory, the null GC is a perfectly valid GC.  If you want objects to be released, in *any* managed language, you need to do so yourself.  Garbage collection is only useful in situations where you actually don't care if the resource is released, only that the underlying resource pool has sufficient capacity the next time you want it (which is usually the case with memory, but not so much with database connections, UI windows, etc.)